# Monopole, Dipole and Quadrupole maps with Healpy

Tags: python, healpy

I am trying to create a map of the monopole (l=0, m=0), dipoles (l=1, m=-1,0,1) and quadrupoles (l=2, m=-2,-1,0,1,2) of the spherical harmonics using Healpy. So far I constructed this extremely simple code with the help of the healpy tutorial:

```
import numpy as np
import healpy as hp

NSIDE=128
m=np.arange(hp.nside2npix(NSIDE))
x=hp.pixelfunc.fit_monopole(m, nest=False)
y=hp.pixelfunc.fit_dipole(m, nest=False)
```

but this just returns the values of the monopole (x) and the value of the monopole and dipole (y):

```
In [22]: print x
98303.5

In [23]: print y
(98303.5, array([ -4.59988602e-01,  -1.81289977e+02,  -9.83040000e+04]))
```

When I try hp.mollview(x) I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

How can I create maps of the monopole and dipoles. Also how do I create maps of the quadrupoles?

Answer (score 0):

A monopole is a constant value on the map, so:

```
m[:] = 0.1
```

For the dipole and quadrupole, you can either:

- get the coordinates of the pixel centers with `hp.pix2ang` and use the geometric definitions of dipole and quadrupole
- create first a set of `C_ell` values with nonzero dipole or quadrupole

  ```
  cl = np.zeros(513, dtype=np.float)
  cl[1] = 100.
  ```

  then transform to a map with `hp.synfast(cl, nside)`.

The first method is exact, the second is approximate but easier.

You should read the `HEALPix Primer` to better understand how `HEALPix` works, google for that.